# MW Word field - macro assigned values get duplicated

Tags: vba, ms-word

In short: I want to fill a field in word using `field.result.text = "Filled Data"`  but everytime I run the macro the text gets added once more.

Full steps:

- Open word (for MS365 - Version 2008)
- type in 'test test data test'
- mark the word 'data'
- press ctrl-F9

In my macro I have

`ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Result.Text = "Filled data"`

When I run this once, I get

`test test Filled data test` or `test test { data } Filled data test`

When I run it a second time I get

`test test Filled dataFilledData test` or `test test { data } Filled dataFilledData test`

How can I fill the field with the desired value only once, and not add my desired value over and over again?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Just highlighting a word and pressing `Ctrl`+`F9` won't create a valid field unless the highlighted words are a valid field code, which "data" isn't. For a list of valid field codes go to the Search box in the Word title bar, type "field codes" (without the quotes), and click on Get Help On. Then in the Help pane choose "List of field codes in Word"

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Seems I first have to define custom document properties.

Comment: Have you looked into using Content Controls?

Comment: Thanks a lot. After looking into it, I actually want to use Content Controls. Made it much easier to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Reformulated Problem: Have a Placeholder in Word which is easy to create and can be filled with content using a VBA-macro.

Solution: Use content-controls.
To assign a content-control: Mark any text -> developer-menu -> PlainTextContentControl

To fill using macro:

```
Sub FillControlwithData()

Dim ControlLoop As ContentControl
 
For Each ControlLoop In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If ControlLoop.Title = "" Then ControlLoop.Title = ControlLoop.Range.Text
    FieldName = Trim(ControlLoop.Title)
    ControlLoop.Range.Text = "some string"
Next ControlLoop

End Sub
```